# How to log for different instances on Spring Project <slf4j>?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, slf4j

There is logback.xml file. For example there are 3 instances running, I wanna see 3 log files.

```
<fileNamePattern>${PATH}/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
```

File pattern is like that above. Whats "%i" ?

How can I log for different instances by using slf4j on Spring Boot project?

Answer (score 1):

The %i is used to number the log files when it log file exceeds its size. For example, using MyLogFile%i.log associated with minimum and maximum values of 1 and 3 will produce archive files named MyLogFile1.log, MyLogFile2.log and MyLogFile3.log. Please refer http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy for more details.

If you want to identify your various instances log files, try adding hostname in name
${PATH}/application-${HOSTNAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log

In your code populate HOSTNAME to instance ip address

Comment: Which keywords can I use instead of HOSTNAME? Fo rexample, a random number, PORT? How can I use?

Comment: @Ozturk, The application will use same port to run on different instances/hosts so 
if you use PORT then you won't be able to distinguish between your hosts, that from which instance this log file is generated.